# Python 3 built-in file write method seems not to work with '\n' for a new line

Tags: python

It seems that, in my codes,

```
f.writelines(str(cos_dis) + str(c_word) + '\n')
```

could not be working with '\n' for a new line in the .txt file. For example, it presents .txt file content like

```
[0.173] [robe] [0.493] [tree][0.274] [book]
```

But I expect is like:

```
[0.173] [robe]
[0.493] [tree]
[0.274] [book]
```

How could I do then? Thank you.

```
for a_word in phrase_model.keys():
    for b_word in phrase_model.keys():
        a_val = phrase_model[a_word]
        b_val = phrase_model[b_word]
        c_word = [a_word, b_word]
        cos_dis = cosine_similarity(a_val, b_val)
        print(str(cos_dis) + str(c_word))
        f.writelines(str(cos_dis) + str(c_word) + '\n')

f.close()

f = open('data01.txt', 'r')
text = f.readline()
text
```

Comment: In what are you opening your file? Some text tools on windows can't display plain `\n`

Comment: Thank you. I find that it works on .txt file while doubling-click it on Windows PC. And it couldn't work in my Jupyter Notebook(browser). Anyway, I got my answer from you. I will accept it as an answer if you like. @h4z3

Comment: But how to choose your comments as an answer? @h4z3